# Swift - protocol extension does not work in building archive

Tags: swift, xcode, protocols

I am having a trouble to understand why below code which implements protocol extension works on normal build but not on archive. This code snippet is originally from [Kingfisher] and I am trying to compile it with my project without having it as framework. As far as I know, the code looks good to me and it actually works on normal build and even run perfectly. But when I tried to archive the project, the compiler complained that `Image`,`ImageView` and `Button` did not confirm the protocol, where I am totally lost and cannot figure out why. I'd appreciate any advices.

```
protocol KingfisherCompatible {
    associatedtype CompatibleType
    var kf: CompatibleType { get }
}

extension KingfisherCompatible {
  var kf: Kingfisher<Self> {
    get { return Kingfisher(self) }
  }
}
extension Image: KingfisherCompatible { }
#if !os(watchOS)
extension ImageView: KingfisherCompatible { }
extension Button: KingfisherCompatible { }
#endif
```

Comment: Can you narrow this down? Is it a result of different optimization settings for debug vs release confirgurations in your build settings? Is it a result of the device you are targeting when archiving? As is there probably isn't enough information here for someone who cannot see your project to identify the root cause.

Comment: @REALFREE did you fix it?